# Last callback not being called using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, restify

I cannot seem to get the last callback (commented as "optional callback") called to send the result back to the browser. Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong? I am using the following modules: async, restify and postgresql for node.js

```
console.log('Start');

var async = require('async');
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.get('/user/creationdate/:username', function(req, res, next) {
    var userName = req.params.username;
    var record;

    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            getUserByName(userName, function(err, user) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                record = user;
            });
        }
    ],
// optional callback
        function(err){
            console.log('5. Following record has been retrieved:' + record);
            res.send(record);
        });

    next();
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

handleError = function handleError(err) {
    if(!err) { return false; }
    else {
        console.log('The following error occurred:' + err);

    }
    return true;
};

function getPgClient(){
    var pg = require('pg');

    var client = new pg.Client({
        user: 'postgres',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'foobar',
        host: '192.168.1.100',
        port: 5432
    });

    client.on('drain', client.end.bind(client)); //disconnect client when all queries are finished

    return client;
}

function getUserByName(userName, callback){
    var client = getPgClient();
    console.log('2. Trying to connect to DB');

    client.connect(function(err) {
        console.log('3. Error connecting to DB:' + handleError(err));
        if(handleError(err)) return callback(err);

        client.query("SELECT created_at FROM users WHERE username='" + userName + "'", function(err, result) {
            if(handleError(err)) return;
            console.log('4. Error occurred:' + err);
            console.log(result);
            console.log(callback);
            callback(null, result);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `async` since you're only calling one asynchronous function. But the reason your callback isn't called is because you're not ending the first function by calling its callback:

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    getUserByName(userName, function(err, user) {
      // call async callback with err and user
      callback(err, user);
    });
  }
], function(err, record) {
  console.log('5. Following record has been retrieved:' + record);
  res.send(record);
});
```

Or, shorter:

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    getUserByName(callback);
  }
], function(err, record) {
  console.log('5. Following record has been retrieved:' + record);
  res.send(record);
});
```

Or, in this case, even shorter (and without the need for `async`):

```
getUserByName(function(err, record) {
  // handle error, or ...
  console.log('5. Following record has been retrieved:' + record);
  res.send(record);
});
```

Comment: Already saw my mistake and came to the same conclusion. I will give you credits for the answer though. I am just prototyping for now but indeed in this example no use for async.

Answer (score 0):

Saw my mistake, missing the line where I should have returned the callback as in:

```
    async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        getUserByName(userName, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            record = user;
            return callback(null, record);
        });
    }
```